# Wordpress Apperance > Customizer stopped working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

there!

I encountered a problem while editing my Wordpress Theme. I have spent 2 days on finding the issue, but useless.

Issue: Wordpress Appearance > Customize page is blank
Link to the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Mzq.png

But, there's one nuance, when I switch to original Twenty Sixteen theme, customizer works pretty well.

What I have tried: Deactivate all plugins, reinstall them, reinstall entire WP.
But I think I have a clue. When I go to appearance > customize page and inspect page, there is an error code like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
customize.php?theme=point&return=https%3A%2F%2Fkritika.kz%2Fwp-admin%2Fthemes.php:5393
```

I press the error link and it gives me the following line of code:

Lines 5392, 5393, 5394:

```
s["point_trending_section"] = {"value":"1","transport":"refresh","dirty":false,"type":"theme_mod"};
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  sprintf(): Too few arguments in <b>/var/www/vhosts/adiletti.kz/kritika.kz/wp-includes/theme.php</b> on line <b>874</b><br />
```

I think the error is with that page break tag, but I do not know how to get rid of that. I will appreciate your help.

Theme I use: Point

Answer (score 0):

Have you reinstalled your theme? What happens if you deactivate all plugins except the theme?

Comment: Yes, I have reinstalled the theme several theme. When I deactivate all the plugins, nothing seems to change. The theme requires 3 plugins, as my WP is new, I don't have any other plugins. Only 3 that come with the theme.